# Equals() method help

Tags: java

I need to write an equals() method for the teams class that is consistent with the provided hashcode method

HashCode method

```
 public int hashCode()
   {
      return this.getPro().hashCode() 
             + this.getTeam().hashCode(); 
   }
```

My equals method, but wont work

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
   {
     ClassName pro = (ClassName) obj;
     return (this.getPro().hashCode() == pro.getPro());
             (this.getTeam().hashCode() == pro.getTeam());
   }
```

Any help would be good

Comment: You are comparing hashCodes with objects.  That isn't going to work.  What are you trying to accomplish?  What do you think hashCode() does?

Comment: If you are going to put objects into a HashSet or HashMap, then two objects that are equal must return the same hashCode, and two objects that return different hashCodes must not be equal.  Two unequal objects can return the same hashCode (there are 4 billion possible hashCodes but many more possible Strings for instance).  You can't define equals() in terms of hashCode(); it may say that two unequal objects are equal.

Answer (score 3):

Here you compare an hashcode (an int) to an object. Plus there is a semicolon in the middle of your statement.

You should try this instead :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;

    if (!pro.equals(myClass.pro)) return false;
    if (!team.equals(myClass.team)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Here you compare the content of objects.

---

After @Bart K. comment here is the way to write your `equals()` method if team or pro are nullable :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;

    if (pro != null ? !pro.equals(myClass.pro) : myClass.pro != null) return false;
    if (team != null ? !team.equals(myClass.team) : myClass.team != null) return false;

    return true;
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - Object.equals() and Object.hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

**On the same topic :**

- [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [How to ensure hashCode() is consistent with equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410236/how-to-ensure-hashcode-is-consistent-with-equals)
- [How to implement hashCode and equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132334/how-to-implement-hashcode-and-equals-method)

Comment: `equals(...)` should also check for `obj == null`.

Comment: It depend if pro and team are nullable or not. And as they don't seem to be nullable (cf. OP `hashCode()`) it's not really necessary.

Comment: No, I didn't mean `pro` or `team` to be null but `obj`. For example, an `ArrayList<ClassName>` can contain `null` references and if you do a `contains(instanceOfClassName)` on it, your implementation would throw a NPE when comparing a `null` to `this`.

Comment: My bad, you're right, I edited the code with a better equals method.

Comment: Thumbs up for not putting `this` in front of method invocations.

Answer (score 2):

1. The hash of two objects being equal *does not mean* the two objects are equal.
2. To check if two conditions are both satisfied, use `&&`.

Thus,

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
   {
     ClassName pro = (ClassName) obj;
     return this.getPro() == pro.getPro() && this.getTeam() == pro.getTeam();
   }
```

Still, your `hashCode()` will not generate good hash, and `equals()` will fail in many cases (e.g. comparing with a non-`ClassName` or `null`). See [*Overriding equals and hashCode in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) for how to implement them correctly. Assuming no derived class, try

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (obj == this) return true;
   if (!(obj instanceof ClassName)) return false;
   ClassName pro = (ClassName)obj;
   <sometype> thisPro = getPro();
   if (thisPro == null || !thisPro.equals(pro.getPro()) return false;
   <sometype> thisTeam = getTeam();
   if (thisTeam == null || !thisTeam.equals(pro.getTeam()) return false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the `==` to compare the objects in the `equals()` method. Most of the time (if not always) if the content of the objects is equal, then the objects themselves are equal.

Comment: The condition (obj == null) is redundant: (null instanceof ClassName) == false

Comment: @Colin: Oops I assumed `==` compares values instead of references. Fixed.

Comment: What "equals" means is totally determined by what you are trying to do.  For instance, you might base equality entirely on an ID field with no regard for any of the other contents.  Generally two objects are equal if they both model the same concept (like 6/8 equals 3/4 (except in music)) or the same real-world object.  If you have two objects, and you put both into a HashSet, and you expect that the set will then contain only one of them and you don't care which, then the two objects are equal.