# How do I write my own comparison operator in Java?

Tags: java

I’ve got a `List<MyObject> list`

And, I want to make use out of the `list.contains()` function.

It doesn’t seem to work at the moment, i.e. there are objects in the list that match, but is not being picked up by the comparator operator.

I’m guessing I need to write my own comparison operator in `MyObject`. What is the way to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override [`public boolean equals(Object o)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) because [`contains`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) uses it:

> `boolean contains(Object o)`
>
> Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

See [How to implement hashCode and equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132334/how-to-implement-hashcode-and-equals-method) for a discussion of simple and correct ways to override `equals`.

You need to be especially careful to override `equals(Object o)` and not just implement `equals(MyObject o)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `equals()` in `MyObject`.

```
public class MyObject
{

     public boolean equals(Object obj)
     {
          if(this == obj)
               return true;
          if((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
               return false;
          // object must be MyObject at this point
          MyObject test = (MyObject) obj;

          // Compare 'this' MyObject to 'test'

     }

     public int hashCode()
     {
          // generate your hash
     }
}
```

Comment: And each time you override the equals, you should override the hashcode too as specified in the javadoc ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You only have to implement your own version of equals and hashcode on MyObject class.

The default equals will not check the attribute you define in a class.  That's why you get the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to implement equals(). It's also useful to implement the Comparable interface, if you ever want to sort your objects E.g.

```
class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
   public int compareTo(MyObject o) {
       // do the compare!
   }

   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      // check equality
   }

}
```

Comment: Not in his case.  He only need to override the equals and hashcode method.  This would be the case if he wanted to sort stuff with a SortedSet for example

Answer (score 0):

Notice the documentation for List's contains method:
[List.contains()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

It states that it used the **equals** method to determine equality and therefore determine if the element exists in the list.

Also, note that when you overload **equals** you must overload **hashCode**.