# How to define a hashcode for class having 3 byte[]?

Tags: java, hashcode

How should I define a `hashCode` for a class having `3 byte[]`?

```
public class Key implements Comparable<Key> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private byte[] subKey1;
    private byte[] subKey2;
    private byte[] subKey3;

    public int hashCode() {  
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement hashCode and equals method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132334/how-to-implement-hashcode-and-equals-method)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hash Code implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Simple hashcode could be to combine the length of all the 3 byte arrays and use it as hashcode.

To generate more complex one, you can read first and last elements of each byte array, convert in to an integer value and combine them to generate hashcode.

I am suggesting you to use the value, because if first and last values are same, then both the classes are most likely ot be similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you google about this or to read Joshua Bloch's book "effective java" which contains a great algorithm how to do this.