# using hashcode() in equal's implementation

Tags: java

Can I use the implementation of `hashCode()` to implement my `equals()` in Java? Or is it a bad practice?

Eg.,

```
public int hashCode()
{
    // some computation based on the internal states
}

public equals(Object o) 
{
     return o instanceof ThisClass ? hashCode() == o.hashCode() : false;
}
```

Comment: It won't be good _enough_. You might get duplicate `int` values that don't necessarily mean that the objects are equal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132334/how-to-implement-hashcode-and-equals-method

Comment: No.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: But if I get two equal objects with different hashcodes, that would be equally bad, woudln't it?

Comment: @OneTwoThree: If that happens, then the implementation of `hashCode` is **broken**.

Comment: Yes, that would violate the contract of equals/hashCode. What *is* allowed is for there to be non-equal objects with equal hashcodes. Your equals/hashCode methods have to be consistent with each other - based on the same information, basically.

Comment: @OneTwoThree: Read the extensive documentation.  Equal objects **must** have equal hashcodes; equal hashcodes do not imply equal objects.

Comment: As per the book, Effective JAVA, if you are overriding the Equals method, you should override the hashcode method as well.

Comment: @ADi: That's exactly the opposite of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is bad practice.  Just because the `hashCode`s are equal DOES NOT mean the objects are equal.

If memberwise comparison is too expensive, then you can use the `hashCode` as an initial check to tell you if the objects are **not** equal.  You still need to do the member comparison if the `hashCode`s match though.

Comment: In other words, you can use `hashCode` as the first check in your `equals` method, and return false if they hashcodes are not the same, but if the hashcodes are equal, you still need to do the other checks.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it works depends on the `hashCode` function. A `hashCode` implementation is required to map equal objects to the same value. It is desirable, as far as possible, to map unequal objects to different values, but that is not required and is often impossible. Many classes have more possible unequal object values than there are `int` values.

If your `hashCode` function does map any pair of objects that are not equal to two different `hashCode` values then two objects of the class are equal if, and only if, they have the same `hashCode` and it could be used in equals.

Do not count on other classes having distinct `hashCode` values for unequal objects. For example, there are more distinct String values than int values, so String's `hashCode` has to map unequal objects to the same `hashCode`.