# Method (x) is undefined for the type String

Tags: java, object

So I have two Strings: type and color. For some reason I can't use "getType" or "getColor". The error comes at the bottom in the second method (public boolean equals(String aClothing)). How can I fix this?

```
public class Clothing {

    // Attributes
    private String type;
    private String color;

    // Constructors
    public Clothing() {
        this.type = "no type yet";
        this.color = "no color yet";
    }

    public Clothing(String aType, String aColor) {
        this.setType(aType);
        this.setColor(aColor);
    }

    // Accessors (getters)
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    // Mutators (setters)
    public void setType(String aType) {

        this.type = aType; // TODO check invalid values
    }

    public void setColor(String aColor) {
        this.color = aColor; // TODO check invalid values
    }

    // Methods
    public String toString() {
        return this.type + " " + this.color;
    }

    public boolean equals(String aClothing) {
        return aClothing != null && this.type.equals(aClothing.getType()) && this.color.equals(aClothing.getColor());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement hashCode and equals method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132334/how-to-implement-hashcode-and-equals-method)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `equals` as an override of [`java.lang.Object`'s `equals` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), which means that your method needs to take `Object` as a parameter:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(object aClothingObj) {
    if (aClothingObj == this) return true; // reference check for this
    if (!(aClosingObj instanceof Clothing)) return false;
    Clothing aClothing = (Clothing)aClothingObj;
    return this.type.equals(aClothing.getType()) &&
           this.color.equals(aClothing.getColor());
}
```

When you override `equals`, you must also override `hashCode`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31*type.hashCode()+color.hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`aClothing` is of type `String` not `Clothing`. 
`String` has no `getType/getColor` method.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you pass in a String for your comparison method:

```
public boolean equals(String aClothing) <--- here your input type is a string
{
    return aClothing != null &&
            this.type.equals(aClothing.getType())&&
            this.color.equals(aClothing.getColor());
}
```

Instead, your method for equals should take in a generic object and override the equals method that all objects have:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object aClothing)
{
    return aClothing instanceof Clothing && aClothing != null && 
            this.type.equals(aClothing.getType())&&
            this.color.equals(aClothing.getColor());
}
```

Comment: Neither of these will actually do what the OP wants, and properly using `@Override` will flag the error. The *correct* signature is `boolean equals(Object)`.

Comment: You are correct. I completely forgot about the correct method signature.